# Is there a property similar to $ x^2 = (x-1)(x+1)+1$ for $ x^3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am looking for a way to decompose $x^3$ in a similar way.

Comment: $x^n - 1$ always factors as $(x - 1)(x^{n-1} + \ldots + x + 1)$; whether it counts as "similar" to what you have for $x^2$ is debatable.

Comment: Thanks, but I was wondering if there was a way to do so with three (multiplying) terms.

Comment: @WeiHu, and you thought that writing "I am looking for a way to decompose $x^3$ in a similar way" would be a satisfying way to articulate this requirement?

Comment: @Ian, I apologize, I had forgotten the  (x−1)(xn−1+…+x+1)(x−1)(xn−1+…+x+1) expansion and for some reason thought that three terms would be required.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out:
$$x^3 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1)+1$$
You say you want three factors.  You can do this but you must use non–real complex numbers.  You can write
$$x^n = (x -\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)...(x-\alpha_n) + 1$$
where the $\alpha_i$ are the $n^\mathrm{th}$ roots of unity.

Comment: This is the right generalization (imo).

Answer (score 0):

I think so: $x^3 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1) + 1$

Comment: Thanks, but I was wondering if there was a way to do so with three (multiplying) terms.

Answer (score 0):

We can write $$x^3= (x-1)(x^2+x+1)+1$$  Also, another representation can be $$x^3 = (x+1)(x^2-x+1)-1$$

Comment: Thanks, but I was wondering if there was a way to do so with three (multiplying) terms.

Comment: @Wei Hu Yes, you can very well write as : $x^3=(x-1)(x+1)(x-1)+x^2+x-1$. It is also possible to have $x^3=(x+1)(x-1)(x+1)-x^2+x+1$. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

$$\small \begin{vmatrix} x+n & 1 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ -n & x+n-2 & 2 & 0 & \ddots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -n+1 & x+n-4 & 3 & \ddots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -n+2 & x+n-6 & \ddots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & x-n+6 & n-2 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & -3 & x-n+4 & n-1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 & -2 & x-n+2 & n\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 & 0 & -1 & x-n \end{vmatrix} = x^{n+1}$$

It goes without saying that $n$ is obviously an integer, since the determinant is always polynomial in $x$. By setting $n=1$, your decomposition can be recovered.